# Rails + rspec + devise = undefined method `authenticate_user!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  protect_from_forgery
end
```

DashboardsController:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

end
```

DashboardsControllerSpec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe DashboardsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Failure/Error: get 'index'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate_user!' for #<DashboardsController:0x007fef81f2efb8>
```

Rails version:  3.1.3

Rspec version:  2.8.0

Devise version: 1.5.3

Note: I also created support/deviser.rb file but that does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: The [devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)) provides a few different ways to integrate devise with rspec.

Answer (score 13):

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe DashboardsController do
  before { controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return true }
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

**Update:**

Using above syntax with latest rspec will give below warning

```
Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from  `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.
```

Use this new syntax

```
  before do
     allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!).and_return(true)
   end
```

Comment: I found the `controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return true` line very helpful. However, the `include Devise::TestHelpers` line is unnecessary and misleading. No methods from `Devise::TestHelpers` are used here, and one reason to stub `authenticate_user!` in the first place is to avoid a coupling with Devise's machinery.

Comment: @evanrmurphy yeap, you are compeltely right, dunno what this include doing in my answer, i will remove it :)

Comment: OMG, thank you for this. I tried everything and nothing was working.  This is the easiest and fastest solution!

Answer (score 7):

Is your model name something other than User?  If it's e.g. Admin, then you need to change your filter to:

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
```

This bit me for a while; I started with User as my model, and later decided to add Devise to a model named Member instead, but I left the original `:authenticate_user!` in my controller and kept getting that error when running RSpec.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the best way to do this is the following in your spec_helper.rb file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

See the [rspec wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had forgotten that I commented out the devise_for line in my routes.rb file.